# Prove that $S$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I actually have to prove that $S$ is compact. But I am stuck on proving it is bounded.

$$S=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 \le z, x+y+z=1 \}$$

If I combine those two inequalities I get $$x^2+y^2 \le 1-x-y$$ In final step I have to get $$.. \le x,y,z \le ..$$

I don't know how to conclude that from what I am given.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+x+y^2+y\le1\\x^2+x+\frac14+y^2+y+\frac14\le1+\frac14+\frac14\\\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2\le\frac32$$ and $z$ of consequence.

Comment: So, to prove that something is bounded I don't have to get $$ m_x \le x \le M_x , m_y \le y \le M_y , m_z \le z \le M_z $$ For example I can get $$ x +y \le 2 $$ Can you explain little bit

Comment: This expression gives you bounds on $x$ and $y$ (if we just consider the $x,y$ coordinates, it is a circle in the plane centered in $\left(-1/2,-1/2\right)$ ). These bounds immediately translate to bounds on $z$.

Comment: To be totally explicit, $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + (y+\frac{1}{2})^2 \leq a$ means $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 \leq a$ (since the $y$-containing bracket is nonnegative), and so $x \leq \sqrt{a} - \frac{1}{2}$ and $x \geq -\sqrt{a} - \frac{1}{2}$.